# C change string between character

Tags: c, string, strtok, string.h

Suppose I have a string "hello_from_here". I would like to change the sub-string that is between the '_', for instance "hello_21223_here".

I suppose that I should use `strtok`, but I've not been successful so far.

So far I was trying to do:

```
char input[] = "this_is_name";
char* first_part = strtok(input, "_");
char* second_part = strtok(strtok(input, "_"), "_");
char output[64];
int pos = 44;
snprintf(output,sizeof(output),"%s%06d%s", first_part, pos, second_part);
```

I know that `snprintf` is correct, but I am failing with `strtok`.

The output is:

```
this000044this
```

My goal output is:

```
this000044name
```

Comment: Because the replacement is not the same length as the part to be replaced, you need an output string that will hold the result. You cannot replace it in the same string.

Comment: Your `snprintf` is undefined behavior. You can't write and read from the same memory at the same time - something is going to overwrite. `first_part` and `second_part` point inside `output` memory. Either choose a different destination for `snprintf`, or a different method of copying. But.. didn't you mean to `strtok(input, ...`?

Comment: "I am failing" is not a problem description. What happened? Why was that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` return value:

> This function returns a pointer to the first token found in the string. A null pointer is returned if there are no tokens left to retrieve.

Since you are passing `input` as the first argument of the second `strtok` it resets the position of the pointer.

A way to solve it is to pass a NULL pointer in subsequent `strtok`, in this case twice since you want to skip the `is` token:

```
//...
char *first_part = strtok(input, "_");
char *second_part = strtok(NULL, "_");
second_part = strtok(NULL, "_");
//...
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yr0cx3xnMvqtLcGD)

Answer (score 1):

This is my attemp

```
#include <stdio.h>

void replacemarks(char *dst, const char *src, char c, const char *r) {
    while (1) {
        while (*src && (*src != c)) *dst++ = *src++;
        if (*src == 0) break;
        *dst++ = *src++;
        if (*src == 0) break;
        const char *cc = strchr(src + 1, c);
        if (cc) {
            const char *rr = r;
            while (*rr) *dst++ = *rr++;
            src = cc;
            *dst++ = *src++;
        } else {
            while (*src) *dst++ = *src++;
            break;
        }
    }
    *dst = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char line[100];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        char src[100], c, r[100], dst[100];
        sscanf(line, "%s %c%s", src, &c, r);
        replacemarks(dst, src, c, r);
        printf("replacemarks(..., \"%s\", '%c', \"%s\") ==> \"%s\"\n",
              src, c, r, dst);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/LhJaaq

Example run with the input

```
hello_from_here _ 21223
this_is_name _ 000044
abracadabra r foo
*one*two*three* * ----
*one*two*three*four* * ----
*one*two*three*four * ----
one*two*three*four* * ----
*one*two*three*four*five* * ----
*one*two*three*four*five * ----
one*two*three*four*five* * ----
```

Output (beautified for Stack Overflow):

```
replacemarks(..., "hello_from_here", '_', "21223")          ==> "hello_21223_here"
replacemarks(..., "this_is_name", '_', "000044")            ==> "this_000044_name"
replacemarks(..., "abracadabra", 'r', "foo")                ==> "abrfoora"
replacemarks(..., "*one*two*three*", '*', "----")           ==> "*----*two*----*"
replacemarks(..., "*one*two*three*four*", '*', "----")      ==> "*----*two*----*four*"
replacemarks(..., "*one*two*three*four", '*', "----")       ==> "*----*two*----*four"
replacemarks(..., "one*two*three*four*", '*', "----")       ==> "one*----*three*----*"
replacemarks(..., "*one*two*three*four*five*", '*', "----") ==> "*----*two*----*four*----*"
replacemarks(..., "*one*two*three*four*five", '*', "----")  ==> "*----*two*----*four*five"
replacemarks(..., "one*two*three*four*five*", '*', "----")  ==> "one*----*three*----*five*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple (even "naive") function:

```
char *replaceDup(const char *haystack, const char *replace, int sep)
{
    char *newstr = malloc(strlen(haystack) + strlen(replace));
    char *wrk = newstr;

    if(newstr)
    {
        while(*haystack && *haystack != sep)
        {
            *wrk++ = *haystack++;
        }
        if(*haystack) haystack++;
        while(*haystack && *haystack != sep)
        {
            haystack++;
        }
        if(*haystack) haystack++;
        while(*replace)
        {
            *wrk++ = *replace++;
        }
        while(*haystack)
        {
            *wrk++ = *haystack++;
        }
        *wrk = 0;
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, good enough, but:

- you need to run `strtok` on input, not on output...
- I would just use `strchr` here
- You need to specify how many characters to copy from `first_part`, otherwise whole string is going to be copied.
- The first part starts at the beginning. The second part starts where the first `_` is.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main() {
    const char input[] = "this_is_name";
    const char *first_part = input;
    const char *second_part = strchr(first_part, '_');
    assert(second_part != NULL);
    size_t first_part_len = second_part - first_part ;
    second_part++; // advance over '_' character
    const char *third_part = strchr(second_part, '_');
    assert(third_part != NULL);
    third_part++;  // advance over '_' character
    char output[64];
    const int pos = 44;
    snprintf(output, sizeof(output), "%.*s_%06d_%s", (int)first_part_len, first_part, pos, third_part);
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

and a short version, without variables, that uses `strcspn` and `strrchr` to find the `_`, with no error checking:

```
snprintf(output, sizeof(output), 
        "%.*s_%06d%s",  (int)strcspn(input, "_"), input, pos, strrchr(input, '_'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```c
  char input[] = "this_is_name";
  char *token, *first_part,*second_part, *third_part;
  char output[64];
  int pos = 44;
  token = strtok (input, "_");
  first_part = token;
  token = strtok (NULL, "_");
  second_part = token;
  token = strtok (NULL, "_");
  third_part = token;

  snprintf (output, sizeof (output), "%s%06d%s", first_part, pos,
        third_part);
```

or something like this:

```c
  char input[] = "this_is_name";
  char *part[3];
  char *token;
  char output[64];
  int pos = 44;
  
  token = strtok (input, "_");
  part[0] = token;
  
  int i = 1;
  while (token != NULL && i < 3) {
    token = strtok (NULL, "_");
    part[i] = token;
    i++;
  }

  snprintf (output, sizeof (output), "%s%06d%s", part[0], pos, part[2]);
```